# Работа List<T> в C#

Tags: c#

Учу Java, но в Unity приходится работать с C#. Подскажите пожалуйста как работает массив `List<T>` в С#? В моем понимании это аналог `ArrayList<>` в Java. `ArrayList<>` работает как динамичный массив, т.е при удалении элемента из середины, права часть смещается влево и другой элемент занимает место удаленного, проще говоря в `ArrayList<>` в середине не может быть пустого места. Подскажите, `List<T>` работает таким же образом или нет, по принципу простого массива? Спасибо.

Comment: Таким же, таким же

Comment: Могу добавить на будущее, что C# Испытал влияние таких языков как  
C++, Java. Например первая версия C# напоминала по своим возможностям Java 1.4, несколько их расширяя. Поэтому вывод практически очевиден....И да - лучше бы этот язык изучить для начала, и многие такие вопросы отпадут быстро %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принципы работы `ArrayList` и `List<T>` на самом деле очень похожи.
Различие лишь в том, что `ArrayList` может одновременно сохранять объекты различных типов, а `List<T>` только одного определённого типа. В остальном практически всё тоже самое.